# How to add dynamic content using ACF on a taxonomy listing?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm going to excuse myself for not adding any code to this question, but there is no need for that because my whole code works fine. My problem is explained next.

I've made a template called `template-listing-products.php` for displaying posts from a custom post type called `products`, which is being used by a page in my WordPress website. In that page I have slideshow where I load images into it using ACF(Advanced Custom Fields) and list all the custom post type taxonomies names with links.

When I click a custom post type taxonomy from that page it redirects me to the template called `taxonomy-products.php` where I have the posts from that taxonomy. My problem is how to use ACF to add dynamic content to those pages? Like the slideshow where I have a page.

**UPDATE**: Problem solved.

I already had a repeater to add images for the slideshow on every taxonomy and I didn't understood why it's not appearing on every category/subcategory in admin. I updated ACF and now works. Maybe this will help someone else.

Comment: So your problem is how to add custom fields to the custom post type `product`?

Comment: No. I can add custom fields to any post from the custom post type. I need to have dynamic content on those pages when I click a taxonomy and list the posts from that taxonomy. Let's say I want to add a slideshow with dynamic loaded images using ACF. How would you do that?

Comment: If you want to create a sideshow, I would recommend to make a custom post type 'slideshow' or 'slide', where each item would have for example a title and an image, which will be shown on the slider.

Comment: Please write your solution as an answer to this question, and accept it as the answer. This will help clean up unanswered questions. Thanks.

Comment: Ok @MatiasVad. Done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I will answer my own question.

Problem solved.

I already had a repeater to add images for the slideshow on every taxonomy and I didn't understood why it's not appearing on every category/subcategory in admin. I updated ACF and now works. Maybe this will help someone else.